# Phusion Passenger application cannot be started

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, raspberry-pi, apache2

I have some problem and have been searching the internet for similar problem but I am still stuck. The problem is regarding apache2 + phusion passenger. I'm hosting on a raspberry pi. I have setup apache2 and virtual host files. But when I tested the application I get application cannot be start from Phusion passenger.

Error from Phusion Passenger when I connect to my localhost on an external PC. Log file:

```
[Mon Jan 11 22:37:07 2016] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) Phusion_Passenger/3.0.13 PHP/5.4.45-0+deb7u2 configured -- resuming normal operations
[ pid=14842 thr=11296008 file=utils.rb:176 time=2016-01-11 22:37:10.346 ]: *** Exception LoadError in PhusionPassenger::Rack::ApplicationSpawner (cannot load such file -- bundler) (process 14842, thread #<Thread:0x158ba10>):
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:325:in `prepare_app_process'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:156:in `block in initialize_server'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:572:in `report_app_init_status'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:154:in `initialize_server'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:204:in `start_synchronously'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:180:in `start'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:129:in `start'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:253:in `block (2 levels) in spawn_rack_application'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:132:in `lookup_or_add'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:246:in `block in spawn_rack_application'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:82:in `block in synchronize'
    from <internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:79:in `synchronize'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:244:in `spawn_rack_application'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:137:in `spawn_application'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:275:in `handle_spawn_application'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `server_main_loop'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:206:in `start_synchronously'
    from /usr/share/phusion-passenger/helper-scripts/passenger-spawn-server:99:in `<main>'
```

This is in my /apache2/sites-available
Virtual host config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName 127.0.0.1
    DocumentRoot /var/www/testPage/public
    RailsEnv development
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    <Directory "/var/www/testPage/public">
        Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I have also switch it to use this config as default by using a2ensite.

ruby -v

```
ruby 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50295) [armv6l-linux-eabihf]
```

rails -v

```
Rails 4.1.8
```

gemfile inside my /www

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.8'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try change permission of folder to 777

```
sudo chmod -r 777 folder_path.
```

Then run bundle again restart apache2 server

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the Apache user has access to Phusion passenger. I'm assuming you're using Rasbpian, a Debian distro. In this case, the Apache user is probably www-data. If you are using CentOS, RedHat, or Fedora, the default Apache username is apache. However that is just the default settings. Certain software (such as cPanel) may change the default apache user. In the case of cPanel, the default apache user is called nobody. Try the following command to enforce apache access.

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /phusion/passenger/installation/path
```